# How to calculate occurrence number of each item in numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`

```py
array_element = [('T10', 'R1T0') ('T20', 'R2T0') ('T31', 'R3T1') ('T21', 'R2T1')
 ('T10', 'R1T0') ('T20', 'R2T0')]
```

I'd like to count number of the elements which are occurred in `array_element` in such way:

`('T10', 'R1T0')` is repeated twice as well as `('T20', 'R2T0')` so the final output:

```py
array_element_count = [('T10', 'R1T0', 2) ('T20', 'R2T0', 2) ('T31', 'R3T1', 1) 
('T21', 'R2T1', 1)]
```

For `array_element` is created by using `numpy`:

```py
dt = np.dtype([('x', np.str_, 16), ('y', np.str_, 16)])
array_element = np.zeros((len(strs),), dtype=dt)
```

I have problems with calculating the occurrence number of each item which will be stored in this array:

```py
dt = np.dtype([('x', np.str_, 16), ('y', np.str_, 16), , ('z', np.int32)])
array_element_count = np.zeros((len(strs),), dtype=dt)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter` approach to count occurances and later merge to existing tuples:

```
[k + (v,) for k, v in Counter(array_element).items()]
```

**Example**:

```
from collections import Counter

array_element = [('T10', 'R1T0'), ('T20', 'R2T0'), ('T31', 'R3T1'), ('T21', 'R2T1'),
 ('T10', 'R1T0'), ('T20', 'R2T0')]

print([k + (v,) for k, v in Counter(array_element).items()])
# [('T10', 'R1T0', 2) ('T20', 'R2T0', 2) ('T31', 'R3T1', 1) ('T21', 'R2T1', 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'unique' attribute in numpy.

```
array_element = np.array([('T10', 'R1T0'), ('T20', 'R2T0'), ('T31', 'R3T1'), ('T21', 'R2T1'),
 ('T10', 'R1T0'), ('T20', 'R2T0')])
uniq_array,count_array = np.unique(array_element,axis=0, return_counts=True)
```

Then you can get the answers.

```
print (uniq_array)
print (count_array)
```

> [['T10' 'R1T0']  ['T20' 'R2T0']  ['T21' 'R2T1']  ['T31' 'R3T1']]
>
> [2 2 1 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas which is fast.

```
import pandas as pd

array_element = [('T10', 'R1T0'), ('T20', 'R2T0'), ('T31', 'R3T1'),
                 ('T21', 'R2T1'), ('T10', 'R1T0'), ('T20', 'R2T0')]
k = pd.Index(tuple(array_element)).value_counts()
list(zip(k.index, k))
```

out

```
[(('T10', 'R1T0'), 2),
 (('T20', 'R2T0'), 2),
 (('T31', 'R3T1'), 1),
 (('T21', 'R2T1'), 1)]
```

or another solution with only numpy:

```
b = np.unique(array_element,return_counts=True, axis=0)
list(zip(zip(*b[0].T.tolist()), b[1]))
```

out

```
[(('T10', 'R1T0'), 2),
 (('T20', 'R2T0'), 2),
 (('T21', 'R2T1'), 1),
 (('T31', 'R3T1'), 1)]
```