# How to count element in matrix numpy like a groupBy pandas?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, group-by

I am approaching for the first time in numpy and I need to understand if there is actually a method to count the occurrences of the elements, as in the pandas group by:
This is the origin matrix:

```
 matrix = [[ 0., 143.],
           [ 0., 170.],
           [ 0., 143.],
           [ 1., 269.],
           [ 0., 170.],
           [ 1., 269.],
           [ 0., 155.],
           [ 1., 269.]]
```

**Result output**: I should do the groupby for the first column, and the number of occurrences is stored in the last column:

```
matrix = [[0., 143., 2],
          [0., 170., 2],
          [1., 269., 3],
          [0., 155., 1]]
```

Comment: The answer can be found in the below link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57184772/how-to-calculate-occurrence-number-of-each-item-in-numpy-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In numpy you can use [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and then concatenate the unique elements with their counts.

```py
import numpy as np
m = np.array([[0., 143.],
              [0., 170.],
              [0., 143.],
              [1., 269.],
              [0., 170.],
              [1., 269.],
              [0., 155.],
              [1., 269.]])
```

```py
rows, counts = np.unique(m, axis=0, return_counts=True)
result = np.concatenate([rows, counts[:, None]], axis=1)
```

or equivalently

```py
result = np.column_stack(np.unique(m, axis=0, return_counts=True))
```

which both result in

```
[[  0.  143.   2.]
 [  0.  155.   1.]
 [  0.  170.   2.]
 [  1.  269.   3.]]
```

Note that the output order of `numpy.unique` is not stable. If the order of the output needs to match the order of first occurrences then you can `numpy.argsort` the result with respect to the indices returned by `numpy.unique`.

```py
rows, indices, counts = np.unique(m, axis=0, return_index=True, return_counts=True)
result = np.concatenate([rows, counts[:, None]], axis=1)[np.argsort(indices)]
```

which results in

```
[[  0.  143.   2.]
 [  0.  170.   2.]
 [  1.  269.   3.]
 [  0.  155.   1.]]
```

Comment: I got it!!! thank you so much! I will want to sort it in descending order based on the occurrence number.

Comment: then switch `np.argsort(indices)` to `np.argsort(counts)`.

Comment: this method has a low computational cost and is great for the amount of data I have to manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

There is [`torch.bincount`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.bincount.html#torch.bincount), but it "only supports 1-d non-negative integral inputs".

Anyway, if you are to count elements, due to float precision errors it is better to work with integers.

For the > 1-d case, you can create a custom function:

```py
def count(x):
    unique_values = set(x)
    counts = [
        (
            tuple(v.tolist()),
            (x == v).all(axis=-1).sum().item()
        )
        for v in unique_values
    ]
    return dict(counts)
```

Which gives counts as a dictionary, similar to standard library [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), that you can reformat later to suit your needs:

```py
>>> count(matrix.to(int))
{(1, 269): 3, (0, 170): 2, (0, 143): 2, (0, 155): 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

keep it simple:

```
from collections import Counter

matrix = [[0., 143.],
          [0., 170.],
          [0., 143.],
          [1., 269.],
          [0., 170.],
          [1., 269.],
          [0., 155.],
          [1., 269.]]

counter = Counter(tuple(vector) for vector in matrix)
matrix_with_count = [[*vector, count] for vector, count in counter.most_common()]
print(matrix_with_count)  # [[1.0, 269.0, 3], [0.0, 143.0, 2], [0.0, 170.0, 2], [0.0, 155.0, 1]]
```